# Run java.exe through ProcessBuilder leads to application hanging?

Tags: java, process, stdout, stdin, processbuilder

I have the following code:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\java", "-cp", "project_folder\\target\\classes", "package.ExternalProcess"); 
    Process p = pb.start();
    OutputStream processOutputStream = p.getOutputStream();
    IOUtils.write("1" + System.lineSeparator(), processOutputStream);
    InputStream processInputStream = p.getInputStream();
    System.out.println("--1--");
    System.out.println(process.isAlive()); // outputs true
    String result = IOUtils.toString(processInputStream, "UTF-8"); //<-- hangs here
    System.out.println("--2--");
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println(result);
```

**ExternalProcess** source:

```
public class ExternalProcess {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String input = null;
        try {
            input = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("processed[" + input + "]");
    }
}
```

The first code produces
`--1--
true`

and hangs on

How to correct program and why does it hangs on?

### P.S.

When I just try to write

```
java -cp project_folder\target\classes package.ExternalProcess
```

from cmd it waiting when I write something to the console and returns expected result

Comment: "java" should be full path to java e.g "/usr/bin/java"

Comment: @Aardvocate Akintayo Olusegun, corrected question. doesn't help

Comment: @Aardvocate Akintayo Olusegun, anyway I have correctly setted PATH environment variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is buffering, in particular, buffering of `Process.getOutputStream()`. If I add:

```
processOutputStream.flush();
```

after:

```
IOUtils.write("1" + System.lineSeparator(), processOutputStream);
```

it works as expected. `IOUtils.write` writes to `processOutputStream`, which just saves the data in a buffer in the parent process, but the data isn't actually sent across the connection to the child process, so the child process hangs in `br.readLine()`, waiting for data that's never coming. The `flush()` call sends the data from the buffer in the parent to the child where it can be read.

(You can see in the javadocs for [`Process.getOutputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--) it says:

> Implementation note: It is a good idea for the returned output stream to be buffered.

While that doesn't *specifically* say the standard implementation is buffered, it's reasonable to assume Oracle will follow their own implementation recommendations.)

If you don't want to have to call `flush()` after every write, you can wrap the `OutputStream` in a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) with `autoFlush` on:

```
PrintStream processPrintStream = new PrintStream(processOutputStream, true);
```

Then instead of using `IOUtils.write`, just use the `PrintStream` methods:

```
processPrintStream.println("1");
```

Because `autoFlush` is on in the `PrintStream`, whenever one of the `println` methods is called (or a byte array or newline is written), the `PrintStream` calls `flush()` on the underlying `OutputStream` for you.